# Remove record from a datatable when record disappears from a mirrored datatable

Tags: c#, .net, database, datagridview, dataset

I have two mirrored datatables (same structure with two primary keys) :

- DataTable_A ---> bound to a datagridView
- DataTable_B ---> filled from a database

Since DataTable_B is filled by a query into database every 2 seconds, I need to mirror the DataTable_A like DataTable_B avoiding filling directly DataTable_A. When a record disappears from DataTable_B i need to delete the record also from DataTable_A. What is the best way to do this ?

Right now I am doing a "for cycle" on each row of DataTable_B and if the row doesn't exist on DataTable_A, I delete it.

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Why are you mirroring the DataTables?  Also, how are you currently filling each DataTable?  Are you completely refreshing DataTable_B from the database every 2 seconds, or just pulling down changes?

Comment: Basically i need to reflect a table from database in a datatable and then in a datagridView, bet i want to do it without have any trouble with UI. Every two second i do a fill of the DataTable_B by a database query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way may be not to have a TableA at all but use a DataView on TableB. That would solve all problems at once. Can you elaborate on why you need the copy?

But otherwise you would want to handle the <strike>RowChanged and TableNewRow</strike> RowDeleted event of TableB

---

A more general idea, after seeing your comments: If it is possible to add a Timestamp column to the table in the database you can run a much more efficient query. And the DataTable.Merge method would do the rest.

Comment: My goal is reflect the situation of a database table on a datagridView. For example i have this query : SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 FROM table1 WHERE date = '2010-09-20'; I need to check almost in real time if the row on the database change and reflect the situations on DatagridView : for example if a row in database is deleted i need to delete it also on datagridView. Pratically the datagridView is a snapshot in real time of the data in a database table.

Comment: And keep a 'stable' view in the Grid? It might be possible with a direct binding, if the number of records isn't too big. Otherwise use the events.

Comment: Record average 1500. But filling Datatable with  dataadapter on table B every two seconds, can i get truly RowDeleted event ? I have a field in each datatable that contains time : HH:MM and a data field in this format : yyyy-MM-dd .

Comment: No, sorry about that RowDeleted, won't work. And the Timestamp won't work for really deleted rows either, you'd need a status column.

Comment: Nut have you tried directly binding to TableB? 1500/2esc doesn't sound overwhelming